# how to solve `no usernames for registry.heroku.com` on heroku container:login?

Tags: docker, heroku-cli

I'm Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS and when I run:

```
heroku container:login -v
```

I get:

```
  heroku-container-registry docker [ 'version', '-f', '{{.Client.Version}}' ] +0ms
  heroku-container-registry docker [ 'login', '--username=_', '--password-stdin', 'registry.heroku.com' ] +41ms
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `no usernames for registry.heroku.com``
 ▸    Login failed with: 1
```

**Does anybody know who to solve this issue?**

Highlights:

- I have Docker up and running. (signed in Docker Hub);
- Heroku CLI is logged in;
- I have tried `sudo heroku container:login -v` but the I got  `▸    not logged in` error;
- I tried to run `sudo heroku login` to then try `sudo heroku container:login` but `sudo heroku login` doesn't open the web page for authentication;
- `sudo heroku login -i` is not an option because I have MFA enabled;